# Setup OpenLdap on Oracle Linux 6

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, oracle-linux, oracle

I am currently trying to setup an openldap server on an Oracle Linux 6 VM (VirtualBox). Packagemanager yum installed openldap version 2.4.40-16.

Following this setup guide:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E41138/html/ch23s04s02.html

I was able to execute all steps except the last one

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f config-mydom-com.ldif
```

which gives me this error

```
ldapadd: invalid option -- 'H'
usage: ldapadd [options]
... (list of options -H not included)
```

When I check "man ldapadd" I can see the option -H:

```
-H ldapuri
Specify URI(s) referring to the ldap server(s); only the protocol/host/port fields are allowed; a list of URI, separated by whetespace or commas is expected.
```

---

1. What am I doing wrong or why is the "-H" option not working?
2. If that setup guide is not valid anymore for openldap 2.4.40, can someone point me to the right steps to setup an openldap server. My last step is to change the cn=admin password to further setting up the domain/schemas.